# don't start xorg on boot

Tags: xorg, startup

I have found a lot of question about Xorg not starting by default, but this is actually what I want.

How can I have Linux Mint (17 Quiana) not start GUI, just the shell (I believe that is supposed to be login shell)?

Answer (score 1):

The following should switch of `mdm` startup at boot for `upstart`:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/mdm.override
```

Just remove the `.override` file if you want the service to start normal.

You can start the service from the console with `sudo service mdm start`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understant, I'm relatively new to linux. If I create mdm.override file in /etc/init/ with just word "manual" mint will use upstart*.conf instead?